# ByteBuf will be cleared when changing the capacity of it in Netty4

Tags: netty, bytebuffer

> Adjusts the capacity of this buffer.  If the {@code newCapacity} is
>   less than the current capacity, the content of this buffer is
>   truncated.  If the {@code newCapacity} is greater than the current
>   capacity, the buffer is appended with unspecified data whose length is
>   {@code (newCapacity - currentCapacity)}.

From the comments on the ByteBuf.capacity(int newCapacity) showed above, 
we excepted that the contents of a ByteBuf before this method will be remained after expand it. But this test case failed.

```
ByteBuf bb =
    PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.directBuffer().order(
        ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

bb.setInt(4, 333);
TestCase.assertEquals(333, bb.getInt(4)); // passed
bb.capacity(4096);
TestCase.assertEquals(333, bb.getInt(4)); // failed
```

We get an assertion failure.

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<333> but was:<0>
```

Anyone can explain it and tell me the way how I can enlarge a ByteBuf without having its contents be changed?

Thanks,
Min

Answer (score 0):

I think its related to this bug report... We are currently investigate it:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1800